# How would a properly format a regular expression for this?

Tags: regex, vba, expression

I am attempting to validate a regex expression for the following procedure:

Example:

```
1234567 Marko's word document 31.10.1998
```

Pseudo Example:

```
[Seven digit #] [space] [Unspecified amount of text] [space] [. delimited date]
```

Can someone assist me on constructing one? This is for the VBA flavor of regex.

Comment: Have you written any code for that? Where are you stuck?

Comment: depend on how strict you want the date validation to be. is `31.09.1998` a valid one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would start here.

```
^\d{7}\s.*\s\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{4}$
```

This is what each section corresponds to.

```
(beginning) = ^
[Seven digit #] = \d{7}
[space] = \s
[Unspecified amount of text] = .*
[space] = \s
[. delimited date] = \d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{4}
(end) = $
```

But the `.*` in the middle might allow more than you are ok with. 
Also the `\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{1,4}$` won't actually filter dates, just decimals. So it will allow a string like "99.99.9999"

You can use this tool to hone it down if you need something more specific:
https://regex101.com/r/dU5lQ3/2

Comment: shouldn't that `\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{1,4}` bit just be `\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}` or does vb not support that?

Comment: I did it because I assumed 1.1.2010 is accepted just as 01.01.2010 would be accepted. But you're right, that depends on the OP. I guess it's safe to remove the \d{1,4} though. Unless they want two digit years or a year prior to the year 1000.